# Submitting a form in a partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

in my _Layout.cshtml file I have

```
@Html.Partial("_SearchPartial")
```

In this partial file I have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("Search")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Question is, how do I make this form post to a particular action method in a particular controller?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)) {
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344.aspx